# Passing class object as a parameter to different class doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im new to WPF mvvm and I cant figure out why the object I'm passing to a different class as a parameter is null but when dispalyed as textbox has value. Easier to understand what I mean with code.

```
class TrainAIViewModel : Screen
    {
        public BindableCollection<Digit> Digits { get; set; }
        public TrainAIViewModel(BindableCollection<Digit> digits)
        {
            Digits = digits;
        }
        private Digit _selectedDigit;

        public Digit SelectedDigit
        {
            get { return _selectedDigit; }
            set 
            {
                _selectedDigit = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedDigit);
            }
        }
        private ICommand _savePatternCommand;

        public ICommand SavePatternCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_savePatternCommand == null)
                    _savePatternCommand = new SavePattern(Digits, SelectedDigit);
                return _savePatternCommand;
            }
            set { _savePatternCommand = value; }
        }
    }
```

```
class SavePattern : ICommand
        {
            #region ICommand Members  
            public BindableCollection<Digit> Digits { get; set; }
            private Digit selectedDigit;
            public SavePattern(BindableCollection<Digit> digits, Digit _selectedDigit)
            {
                Digits = digits;
                selectedDigit = _selectedDigit;
            }
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return true;
            }
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
            {
                add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
                remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
            }

            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                if(selectedDigit!=null)MessageBox.Show(selectedDigit.Name);//this is the problem
                //selectedDigit doesnt exist for some reason. I need to get value currently selected in combobox and can't see why it doesnt work
                MessageBox.Show(Digits.Count.ToString());//this works
            }
            #endregion

        }
```

So passed BindableCollection works and it has the amount of objects it has in viewmodel class. All the more I don't understand why selectedDigit is null especially since textblock displaying its value works.

```
ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Margin="0,20,0,0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDigit}"
                  x:Name="Digits">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name="DigitName" Text="{Binding Name}"
                               />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="SelectedDigit_Name"/>
//this shows the value in the combobox. Did this to test if my variable selectedDigit actually has the value of currently selected combobox item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setter of `SelectedDigit` you must update the `SavePatternCommand.selectedDigit`.

Either make the `field` accesable from outside the class or you could force a new initialization.

1. Make it accessable

   ```
   class SavePattern : ICommand
   {
       public BindableCollection<Digit> Digits { get; set; }
       public Digit SelectedDigit { get; set; }
   }

   public Digit SelectedDigit
   {
       get { return _selectedDigit; }
       set 
       {
           _selectedDigit = value;
           NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedDigit);

           SavePatternCommand.SelectedDigit = value;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Force a new initialization

   ```
   public Digit SelectedDigit
   {
       get { return _selectedDigit; }
       set 
       {
           _selectedDigit = value;
           NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedDigit);

           _savePatternCommand = null; //setting the field to null, will "activate" the initialization of the command
           NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SavePatternCommand); //notify a change done to the command
       }
   }
   ```

But, it would be better if you didn't use the command like this at all, but instead use the `CommandParameter`.

You didn't show the part in your `XAML` where you are actually using your `SavePatternCommand`, but I assume you are using it in a `Button` it could look like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding SavePatternCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDigit}" />
```

The `CommandParameter` will now be used automatically by the `Command`.

And your `Execute` method should look like this:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    //the argument `parameter` will have the `CommandParameter` that gets specified in the `XAML`

    //cast the object to Digit
    var parameterAsDigit = parameter as Digit;
    if (parameterAsDigit == null)
        return;


}
```